# Use props in HoC parameters

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm trying to use props values in my HoC but i'm struggling quiet hard

Here is my code :

```js
export default compose(
  connectEndpoint({
    discussion: getDiscussionRequest(
      props.message.discussionid,
      {
        refreshing: true
      },
      props.message.flag
    ),
    contacts: getContactsByFlagRequest({ refreshing: true }, props.message.flag)
  }),
```

and here is the connectEndpoint function :

```js
export default requests =>
  compose(
    connect(() =>
      withSingleApi(typeof requests === "function" ? requests() : requests)
    )
  );
```

I'm trying to use my props value when i call "connectEndpoint" but i don't know what syntax should i use to have access to "props". I tried to use "withProps" but with no success on this case

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you are using  `connect` within your `connectEndPoint` HOC , you can implement the `requests` property of your `connectEndPoint` HOC as a function and pass on the state and props from connect to it.

```
export default requests =>
  compose(
    connect((state, props) =>
      withSingleApi(typeof requests === "function" ? requests(state, props) : requests)
    )
  );
```

and use it like

```
export default compose(
  connectEndpoint((state, props) => ({
    discussion: getDiscussionRequest(
      props.message.discussionid,
      {
        refreshing: true
      },
      props.message.flag
    ),
    contacts: getContactsByFlagRequest({ refreshing: true }, props.message.flag)
  }));
```

---

The reason you were not receiving props in your implementation was because connectEndPoint is a function that is being called and only the return value from it is being used to render the component which receives the props

Comment: Thanks a lot, i never had this case before, i should take a training course on HOCs to better understand all the mecanics !
Btw i only used (props) not (state,props), can you explain me why did you add state to the arguments ?

Comment: connects mapStateToProps provides both state and props, where state is the state from redux store, incase you need it somewhere, I added it as an example. You can avoid it if you don't require it